# CPLEX Python API installment on Mac big sur problem CpoException

Tags: python, cplex

when I install Cplex python API on my Macbook. Cplex is successfully installed. When running an example in python, following error happend:

File "/Users/lily/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docplex/cp/solver/solver_local.py", line 102, in **init**
raise CpoException("Executable file should be given in 'execfile' context attribute.")

CpoException: Executable file should be given in 'execfile' context attribute.

Has anyone met similar problem? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

let me share the [bus example](https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-66940178db6) with this :

```
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel

mdl = CpoModel(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(0,1000,name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(0,1000,name='nbBus30')
mdl.add(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300)
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

#call CPLEX 20.1
msol=mdl.solve(execfile='C:\\ILOG\\CPLEX_Studio201\\cpoptimizer\\bin\\x64_win64\\cpoptimizer.exe')
#call CPLEX 12.10
msol=mdl.solve(execfile='C:\\ILOG\\CPLEX_Studio1210\\cpoptimizer\\bin\\x64_win64\\cpoptimizer.exe')

print(msol[nbbus40]," buses 40 seats")
print(msol[nbbus30]," buses 30 seats") ​
```