# IBM CP Optimizer Community Edition

Tags: websphere, python-3.8, cplex, docplex

I get the following message when using docplex in Python:

Solver error: Problem size limit exceeded.
CP Optimizer Community Edition solves problems with search spaces up to 2^1000.
Unrestricted version options (including academia) at https://ibm.co/2s0wqSa

I have the academic version, but the license for CP Optimizer does not connect.
I have made the CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR201 and CPLEX_CPXCHECKLIC_BINDIR environment variables. But I can not find my API key to set CPLEX_STUDIO_KEY. Where do I find my API key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the solve parameter you can set the path for the right cplex cp engine on your machine.

```
msol=mdl.solve(execfile='C:\\ILOG\\CPLEX_Studio201\\cpoptimizer\\bin\\x64_win64\\cpoptimizer.exe')
```

See [CPLEX Python API installment on Mac big sur problem CpoException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69245657/cplex-python-api-installment-on-mac-big-sur-problem-cpoexception/69584118#69584118) for full example